# How to set angularjs dropdown option value?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-options

I have succesfully setup the option in both dropdowns.

In my dropdown one is dependent to another

Suppose in my database Parent name is Sally and child name is SallyChild2,when an updating this page, i need to populate the entire data 
with select this particular parent name as Sally and childname as SallyChild2

My database value is Parent - Sally and Child - SallyChild2

So i want to change Child - SallyChild1

So I hard coded as this wat but not working

```
$scope.selectedParent="Sally";
$scope.selectedChild="SallyChild2";
```

But its not working

This is my script.js

script.js

```
var app=angular.module('TestApp', ['angular.filter','ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
    .state('category',
    {
    views : {   
        "body" :
    {
        url : '/category',
        templateUrl : 'category.html',
        controller : 'TestController'
    }
    }   

    })

    .state('category.subcategory',
    {
    url : '/subcategory',
    views : {                              
    "subbody@category" :
    {
    templateUrl : 'sample.html',
    controller : 'SampleController'              
    }
    }
    })
});

app.controller('MainController', MainController);

function MainController($scope,$state)
{
    alert("This is MainController")

    $scope.getCategory=function()
    {
    $state.go('category');
    }


}

app.controller('TestController', TestController);

//TestController.$inject['dataservice'];

function TestController($scope, $state){


    $scope.data=[
     {
      "parentName": "George",
      "childName": "George Child1"          
     },
     {
      "parentName": "Folly",
      "childName": "FollyChild1"         
     },
     {
      "parentName": "Sally",
      "childName": "Sally Child1"          
     },

     {
      "parentName": "George",
      "childName": "GeorgChild2"          
     },
     {
      "parentName": "Folly",
      "childName": "FollyChild2"         
     },
     {
      "parentName": "Folly",
      "childName": "Infant Food"          
     },
     {
      "parentName": "Sally",
      "childName": "SallyChild2"          
     }
    ];

    $scope.selectedParent="Sally";
    $scope.selectedChild="SallyChild2";

    function onParentChange(parent){
      if(!parent){
    $scope.child = undefined;
      }
    }


    $scope.getValue=function()
    {
    alert("Call to Sample Controller")

    var currentState = $state.current.name;
    var targetState = 'category.subcategory';

    if(currentState === targetState)
      $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
    else
    $state.go(targetState);
    $state.go(".subcategory");

    //$state.go('category.subcategory');
    }
}


app.controller('SampleController', SampleController);

function SampleController($scope,$state)
{
    alert("This is SampleController")

}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="TestApp">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.8/angular-filter.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-ui-router.js"></script>    
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-filter.js"></script>
  </head>

    <body ng-controller="MainController">
        <a href="#" ng-click="getCategory()">Click to Category</a>
        <div ui-view="body"></div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

category.html

```
  <div>    
    <hr>

    <div class="col-md-3"> 
      <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleSelect1"><b>Parent</b></label>
      <select ng-model="selectedParent"
        ng-init="selectedParent = null"
        ng-change="onParentChange(selectedParent)"
        class="form-control" id="data">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in data | orderBy:'parentName'| groupBy:'parentName'">{{key}}</option>           
      </select>
    </div>              
      </form>  
    </div>      
    <div class="col-md-3">      
      <form>    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleSelect1"><b>Child Names</b></label>
      <select class="form-control" id="childnames" ng-model="child" 
        ng-disabled="!selectedParent"
        ng-options="data.childName for data in data| filter: {parentName:selectedParent} | removeWith:{childName : 'Infant Food'}" ng-change="getValue()">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
      </select>
    </div>          

      </form>     
  </div>
    <div ui-view="subbody"></div>
  </div>
```

sample.html

```
<div>
    Sample Controller
</div>
```